# How can I print each text element on a new line after a tab indent?

Tags: r

I want to be able to print each text element on a new line after one tab indent.

---

**Desired Results**

---

```
   "A" 
   "B" 
   "C"
```

---

**Code**

---

```
LETTERS[1:3]
```

---

**Output**

---

```
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a combination of `cat` and `paste` (and the special characters `\t` (tab) and `\n` (newline)), e.g.:

```
cat(paste0("\t", LETTERS[1:3], "\n"))
```

Comment: For printing the quotes too: `cat(paste("\t", LETTERS[1:3], "\n", sep ="\""))`